# Run 10 batch job in parallel kotlin

Tags: kotlin, asynchronous, batch-processing, batch-normalization

I have one batch, that makes some job in a sync method. It can take some time. For optimizing, I want to do create async method, that will execute 10 batches in one time in parallel. Is it possible in Kotlin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This totally depends on the type of your task, do you want to execute multiple CPU boung long running tasks, then you should go with [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html). On the other hand if you want to execute multiple async calls which are not as much CPU intensive, then you can look into [kotliln coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-basics.html)

Just to give an example, when using corotuines first you need to define your task, let say you have a suspending function for it, as following

```
suspend fun myTask(param: SomeParam)
```

Now you want to start execution of 10 tasks in parallel, then you do

```
runBlocking {  // start a coroutine it is like a thread, but very lightweight
   launch(Dispatcher.Default){ myTask(param) }    // launch individual coroutine for every parallel task
   launch(Dispatcher.Default){ myTask(someOtherParam) }
   ...
   launch(Dispatcher.Default){ myTask(yetAnotherParam) }
   //  Choose appropriate dispatcher (Main, IO or Default)
}
```

[`launch`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/launch.html) is a coroutine builder which starts a coroutine without blocking the calling thread. you can also use async if you want to return some result.

There are lots of options available, I suggest you look into [Coroutines guide](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-guide.html)

Comment: Hello @mightyWOZ
Let's assume, that I have a function that I want to call 4 times in parallel
fun method (params)
How to use couritines here?